# Is there any way to add multiple on_get methods under single class resource in Falcon?

Tags: python-3.x, api, falconframework

If suppose we want to implement the following end points in single class resource, Is there any way to put multiple **on_get** methods within single resource that would differentiate each end point ? Because it makes sense to put under single class as they are pretty much closely related.

Possible end points :

/api/{id}

/api/v1/{id}

/api/{id}/appended

/api/v1/appended/{id}

Comment: I suggest next time you also write full code so it will help to understand requirements properly.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, in Falcon 2.0, the [`add_route`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/api.html#falcon.API.add_route) method supports a `suffix` keyword argument which allows you to use a single resource class for multiple endpoints.
Some example code:

```py
class UserResource:

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.media = self.repository.find_all()

    def on_get_single(self, req, resp, user_id):
        resp.media = self.repository.find_user(user_id)


resource = UserResource()

api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/users', resource)
api.add_route('/users/{user_id}', resource, suffix='single')
```

From the docs of `falcon.API.add_route`

> If a suffix is provided, Falcon will map GET requests to
> `on_get_{suffix}()`, POST requests to `on_post_{suffix}()`, etc. In this
> way, multiple closely-related routes can be mapped to the same resource. For
> example, a single resource class can use suffixed responders to distinguish
> requests for a single item vs. a collection of those same items.

If you will to see another relevant example of this usage present in Falcon's documentation, [read it here](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/faq.html#how-do-i-implement-both-posting-and-geting-items-for-the-same-resource).

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. Clean example.

Answer (score 2):

**Update on Falcon 2.0:**

Now Falcon 2.0 support "suffix" out of the box in add_route. For more info refer [this](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/api.html#falcon.API.add_route). You can use the following code:

```
class CatalogItem(object):
    # Logic for /api/{id}
    def on_get(self, req, resp, id):
        resp.res.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        res.body = json.dumps({'status': True, 'message': 'success'})


    # Logic for /api/v1/{id}
    def on_get_v1(self, req, resp, id):        
        resp.res.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        res.body = json.dumps({'status': True, 'message': 'success'})


    # Logic for /api/v1/appended/{id}
    def on_get_appended(self, req, resp, id):
        resp.res.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        res.body = json.dumps({'status': True, 'message': 'success'})

app = falcon.API()
app.add_route('/api/{id}', CatalogItem())
app.add_route('/api/v1/{id}', CatalogItem(), suffix='v1')
app.add_route('/api/v1/appended/{id}', CatalogItem(), suffix='appended')
```

**For Falcon older than V2.0:**

I hope the following code will help you if you have the same logic for all said route:

```
class CatalogItem(object):
    def on_get(self, id):
        return self._collection.find_one(id)

app = falcon.API()
app.add_route('/api/{id}', CatalogItem())
app.add_route('/api/v1/{id}', CatalogItem())
app.add_route('/api/v1/appended/{id}', CatalogItem())
```

This code route to the same **on_get** method. But I still suggest that you write a separate class with the different *on_get* method. And if most of the code is similar than you can write helper function and call it whenever needed.

Also,
As you mention that "you want to put multiple on_get methods within a single resource that would differentiate each endpoint" which is not possible, but there is a workaround.

You can use the same **on_get** method and based on the route you can use different logic for each.

```
class CatalogItem(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp, id):
        route_path = str(req.path) 
        if route_path.startswith("/api/v1/appended/"):
            # Logic for /api/v1/appended/
            resp.res.status = falcon.HTTP_200
            res.body = json.dumps({'status': True, 'message': 'success'})
        elif route_path.startswith("/api/v1/"):
            # Logic for /api/v1/
            resp.res.status = falcon.HTTP_200
            res.body = json.dumps({'status': True, 'message': 'success'}) 
        elif route_path.startswith("/api/"):
            # Logic for /api/
            resp.res.status = falcon.HTTP_200
            res.body = json.dumps({'status': True, 'message': 'success'})



app = falcon.API()
app.add_route('/api/{id}', CatalogItem())
app.add_route('/api/v1/{id}', CatalogItem())
app.add_route('/api/v1/appended/{id}', CatalogItem())
```

Comment: If this is not what you looking for then please let me know, I try to help you.

Comment: This has single on_get which would eventually return same response for all end points. The question here is whether multiple on_get methods are possible under single resource class which would return different response with slight variation based on the mapped route.

Comment: @YugendharAnveshra Based on your comment I updated the answer, let me know if it solves your problem or not?

Comment: Thanks for the workaround though. However, it still has single on_get method. How do we represent if the routes are /api/v1/{id} and /api/v1/{id}/appended. I'm expecting if there is something like `alias` keyword as discussed something similar in the [issue](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/issues/584)

Comment: As mentioned in the issue, Is there a possibility to add route as `api.add_route('/route/', route_resource, suffix='whatever')` with signature as 

`on_get_whatever(usual stuff)`